Getting both the non filtered values and filtered from a slicer powerbi
I have a table called Data with two clumns : Data[Class] and Data[value] .
I have 2 table visuals in my powerBi and one slicer.
I want to use the slicer to select some catgories and show the data of the selected categories in one table and the data of the unselected categories in the other (dynamically with each selection on the slicer)
Example
Data :



Class
value




TypeA
20


TypeB
13


TypeC
52


TypeD
2



If I select TypeA and TypeC in the slicer :
selected visual :



Class
value




TypeA
20


TypeC
52



unselected visual :



Class
value




TypeB
13


TypeD
2



My approach :

I created a new table Categories[Class] with just the values of Data[Class] and linked my slicer to it instead.
I created a mesure to calculate if a class is not selected :

Nonselected = 
VAR selectedClasses = DISTINCT(Categories[Class]) 
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX(
            'Data', 
            IF(
                NOT 'Data'[Class] IN selectedClasses, 
                1, 
                0
            )
        )
    )


I used the mesure to filter on the second visual.

My approach did nnot work , can you please help ?
Thank you

you can create a table for selection
Table 2 = DISTINCT('Table'[Class])

Do not create relationship between two tables.
Then create a measure
MEASURE =
VAR _list =
    CONCATENATEX ( 'Table 2', 'Table 2'[Class], "," )
RETURN
    IF ( CONTAINSSTRING ( _list, MAX ( 'Table'[Class] ) ), 1, 0 )

add this measure to one visual filter and set to 1

You will see the selected type.
add this measure to another table visual filter and set to 0

then you can see the unselected type

Is it the right code ? because I do not have year month data

sry, pasted the wrong code. I just fixed it. pls have a try.

Thank you for the code but it is not my usecase , I should be able to randomly select items on the slicer (not in alphabetical order) and still get the rest of the items on the second visual

what do you mean by randomly select item (not in alphabetical order)? No matter what you select in the filter visual , one table visual will show the rest items. you can have a try.

Exactly , it does not work because there is (max) , it is not necessarly the max item that it is unselected

could you pls update the sample data and expected output then I can update the answer?
